# ldconfig finds a library, ldd still doesn't

Tags: software-installation, libraries, shared-library

**EDIT**: Found the answer -- the binary is 32bit, I was installing 64bit libraries. Installing like `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386` works.

I'm trying to get Dwarf Fortress to work under Ubuntu 14.04. It comes as a dynamically linked binary with some dependencies that I don't have yet.

So I run `ldd` on it:

```
$ ldd libs/Dwarf_Fortress
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76e3000)
libSDL-1.2.so.0 => not found
libgraphics.so => /home/remco/src/df_linux/libs/libgraphics.so (0xf72af000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/remco/src/df_linux/libs/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf71d1000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf718b000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/remco/src/df_linux/libs/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7170000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf6fc1000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf6fa5000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76e4000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => not found
libSDL-1.2.so.0 => not found
libSDL_image-1.2.so.0 => not found
libGLU.so.1 => not found
libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 => not found
```

Let's go for the first. `apt-file search` tells me that `libSDL-1.2.so.0` is provided by 
'libsdl1.2debian', so I install that.

Sure enough:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 mei 10 06:40 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0 -> libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 427600 mei 10 06:40 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
```

And this directory is mentioned in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`.

`ldconfig` works too, at least, apart from somee warning messages (sorry for the Dutch):

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libSDL
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Kan status van /lib/i686-linux-gnu niet opvragen: Bestand of map bestaat niet
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Kan status van /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu niet opvragen: Bestand of map bestaat niet
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Pad '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' is meerdere malen opgegeven
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Pad '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' is meerdere malen opgegeven
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
libSDL-1.2.so.0 -> libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
```

The "meerdere malen opgegeven" errors mean that the path occurs multiple times in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, seems OK to me.

The last line tells me that the right file has been found. *Unfortunately, `ldd` still gives the exact same output as above*.

Is there a step I'm missing? Do I need to reload something? As far as I can see, `ldconfig` works correctly, but `ldd` still doesn't find the file, and I thought it would.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that Dwarf_Fortress was a 32-bit binary (I found out with `file Dwarf_Fortress`), and the libraries I was installing were 64-bit. Adding `:i386` at the end of the apt-get command installs the i386 versions of the libraries, and that works.